# I don't have a "My Sites" button in my WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I have some problems the solutions of which are in "My sites" tab as I googled them. But the problem is that I don't actually have a `My Sites` where it should be:

[image: What it should be]

Above is what it should be and below what I have

[image: My WordPress]

P.S. The update button has nothing to do with it.

Comment: You'll only have that link if you've got a multi-site WordPress setup. This isn't very common, and there aren't any fixes to be had in there; it just lets you access the multiple WordPress installs.

Comment: Hello thanks for your answer, My global problem is to copy or clone some posts to different pages and the only way I found it was 
Go to My Sites → Site → Posts/Pages
Click the ellipses menu (the three vertical dots) to the right of the post or page you want to copy.
Select Copy

And If I go to just `POSTS` which I have there is no eclipses menu and no copy

BTW I don't need the copy all content method because it's different from what I want

Comment: It sounds like you're reading instructions for a multi-site WP install when you have a single-site one. It's been a while since I used WordPress, but the docs you're reading may also rely on a plugin. There are many "clone posts" plugins in a quick Google.